# How to Make If statement for a specific Image source?

Tags: javascript, css, switch-statement

I have this line in my program (Run in Dreamweaver) which is the following:

```
function go() {
if((document.test.test1.src == document.test.test2.src && document.test.test2.src == document.test.test3.src ))

......
......
.....
}
```

This function runs when I have 3 different images which when either of the three equal each other in the page. However, how would I make it to specify which images to equal each other, instead of just doing any of the three.

For ex, if one image is titled 'x' if all three test1,test2,test are of value 'x' it will run the function and display this message, however, it displays the same message for the other images (If all equal 'y') Id like to have separate messages somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd separate the comparison to a separate function with current image element as parameter and use this method with different image objects:

```
function compare(imgElem){
  if((document.test.test1.src == document.test.test2.src && document.test.test2.src == document.test.test3.src ))
    console.log(imgElem.id,"triggered");
    // or something else
  }
}

compare(document.test.test1);
compare(document.test.test2);
compare(document.test.test3);
```

**However** the solution might not be accurate depending on how many elements you're comparing. For large number of elements, try using a map.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `if` statement, you can place a `switch`/`case` block to test which image it is of 'x', 'y', etc. It doesn't matter which image's `src` you check, since you've already checked that they are all equal.

i.e.

```
if((document.test.test1.src == document.test.test2.src && document.test.test2.src == document.test.test3.src ))
    switch (document.test.test1.src) {
        case "x":
            // Do stuff
            break;
        case "y":
            // Do other stuff
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand you correctly, within your code you could add a switch e.g.

```
switch (document.test.test1.src) {
      case 'y':
        ........
        break;
      case 'x'
        ........
        break;
}
```

"........" designates what you want to run if the object equals y or x respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly simple to implement

```
var a=document.test.test1.src;
var b=document.test.test2.src;
var c=document.test.test3.src

var fn: {
    x: function() { alert(messageX); },
    y: function() { alert(messageY); },
    z: function() { alert(messageZ);}
};

if(a==b && b==c) {
    if(fn.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
        fn[a](); //you can also use 'b' or 'c' since they're all equal 
    }
}
```