# Switch case not working for Images stored in array

Tags: javascript, css

Relating to my previous question , I had images which(if three of a specific image) where the same, I wanted a message to appear, I followed several guidelines from my previous question but I still cant get it to work.

Previous question: [How to Make If statement for a specific Image source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625077/how-to-make-if-statement-for-a-specific-image-source)

It always prints the else statement, even if 3 images of x appear, it prints nothing but the main message, the same problem occurs when the 3 images of y appear(at once) or z. Any help would be much appreciated.

new code (Tad bit) :

```
function xyz()  { 

    if((document.test.test1.src == document.test.test2.src && document.test.test2.src == document.test.test3.src ))
        switch (document.test.test1.src == document.test.test2.src == document.test.test3.src) {
            case "x":
                document.test.banner.value =("3 for x")// Do stuff
                break;
            case "y":
                document.test.banner.value =("5 for y")
                break;
            case "z":
            document.test.banner.value =("8 for z")
            break;
        }

    else 
    {
        document.test.UserTokens.value=document.test.UserTokens.value-document.test.bet.value; 
        document.test.banner.value="No match - You lost ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a problem:

```
switch (document.test.test1.src == document.test.test2.src == document.test.test3.src)
```

The Switch statement evaluates the value you put into the parenthesis. You are comparing the `.src`s, so it will return a Boolean for the Switch to evaluate instead of the strings you are hoping for. No need to compare them in the Switch, seeing as we already know that they are all the same. We just need to know one of them.

Secondly, I found it very interesting that you used the syntax `(a == b == c`.
I did some testing and this is what that does. It is equivalent to `((a==b)==c)`. It evaluates from left to right. First, `(a==b)` which will return a Boolean. It then compares that Boolean to c, and I'm guessing that your "c" isn't a Boolean, so it will always return `false`.

Looking back at your previous question

```
switch (document.test.test1.src) {
      case 'y':
        ........
        break;
      case 'x'
        ........
        break;
}
```

,as suggested by dewd, seems to be an appropriate choice if you decide to stick with the Switch.

Hope that helped.

Comment: I made it so I don't compare them in the switch, it still results in the same problem

Comment: A suggestion on how to fix it would certainly be appreciated :s. Seeing the lack of people even attempting to answer this question, you seem to be my only hope.

Comment: Haha. Sorry. I leave the computer for a moment and miss someone trying to get some help =/

First question: are there curly brackets containing the Switch in your code? that might be a good first step.

Second question: what are the `.src`s exactly?

Comment: The .src are the source of the images defined in my beggining code

Comment: And yes there is curly brackets

Comment: Okay. Well, unless the value of `document.test.test1.src` exactly equals `"x"`, the cases won't run. You can also add a `default` to the Switch to see if none of the cases are being run, like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

Comment: i tried that before, i added a default to the switch and removed the else statement, nothing displayed afterwards only the images moved.

Comment: Hmmm... Well, what is an actual example value of `document.test.test1.src` exactly? If the `.src` is referring to an image then I would expect it to have an extension such as .png or .jpg, instead of just being "x". Have you tried to add on the default with the code as it is now? Just making it run something to `console.log('no cases');` to see whether or not it is going into a case like you want it to?