# Javascript Switch case doesn't work even if conditions are true

Tags: javascript

As my previous questions I coudn't get any answers which solved my problem, I've decided to post my entire code to determine the issue. The problem is when the button is pressed, even if one of the three images is the same (Equals all the others) for instance(three 1's appear, or three 2's appear) no message that I entered in the program is outputted instead, nothing happens.

Here is my original question([Switch case not working for Images stored in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627073/switch-case-not-working-for-images-stored-in-array))

The HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name=slots onSubmit="rollem(); return false;">
            <tr>
                <th align=right>UserTokens:</th>
                <td align=left>
                    <input type=box size=5 name=UserTokens READONLY value=25>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align=right>Your bet:</th>
                <td align=left>
                    <input type=box size=5 name=bet>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type=submit value="Spin the slots">
                </th>
                <center>
                    <table cellspacing=5 cellpadding=2 border=0>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src=number1test.gif name=slot1>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src=number2test.gif name=slot2>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src=number3test.gif name=slot3>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type=text readonly size=33 name=banner>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>

</html>
```

And my JS (at the end of the `<body>`):

```
slotitem = new Array('number1test', 'number2test', 'number3test'); // create array for each slot item image

tokens = 100; // starting tokens

function stopplay() { // call function

    if (document.slots.UserTokens.value < tokens) // if usertokens are less than value..
    {
        alert("You lost all your tokens")

    } else // otherwise, how much the user gained
    {
        alert("You gained " + (document.slots.UserTokens.value - tokens) + " Token pieces.   ");
    }
}

function rollem() {

    if (Math.floor(document.slots.UserTokens.value) < Math.floor(document.slots.bet.value)) {
        alert("Your bet is larger than your token amount")

    }

    if (document.slots.bet.value > 1) {
        document.slots.banner.value = "Bet is " + document.slots.bet.value + " UserTokens pieces";
    } else {
        document.slots.banner.value = "Bet is " + document.slots.bet.value + " UserTokens piece";
    }

    counter = 0;
    spinem();

}

function spinem() { // speed of randomly generated pictures

    turns1 = 10 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 5))

    for (a = 0; a < turns1; a++)

    {
        document.slots.slot1.src = "" + slotitem[a % 3] + ".gif";
    }

    turns2 = 10 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 5))

    for (b = 0; b < turns2; b++)

    {
        document.slots.slot2.src = "" + slotitem[b % 3] + ".gif";
    }

    turns3 = 10 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 5))

    for (c = 0; c < turns3; c++)

    {
        document.slots.slot3.src = "" + slotitem[c % 3] + ".gif";
    }

    counter++;

    if (counter < 25) {
        setTimeout("spinem(counter);", 50);
    } else {
        checkmatch();
    }

}

function checkmatch() {
    // the problem is here, where the cases seem to never happen, the program just goes to the else statement, and when one case is true on the webpage, it doesnt display anything(Nor the else statement)
    if ((document.slots.slot1.src == document.slots.slot2.src && document.slots.slot2.src == document.slots.slot3.src))
        switch (document.slots.slot1) {
        case "number1test":
            document.slots.banner.value = ("You got 3 in a row for 1's") // Do stuff
            break;
        case "number2test":
            document.slots.banner.value = ("You got 3 in a row for 2's")
            break;
        case "number3test":
            document.slots.banner.value = ("You got 3 in a row for 3's")
            break;
    } else {
        document.slots.UserTokens.value = document.slots.UserTokens.value - document.slots.bet.value;
        document.slots.banner.value = "No match - You lost " + document.slots.bet.value + " Token piece(s)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Indent your code. It'll make it much easier to read.

Comment: and give only the important stuff please...

Comment: I tried only giving tid-bits of my code in my previous questions, no answers solved my problem.

Comment: That code can never work. First you compare `document.slots.slot1.src` to something else, which means that `document.slots.slot1` can't be a string (or if it is, then `document.slots.slot1.src` will be undefined).

Comment: Btw, you're not declaring _any_ variable, `a`, `b`, `c`, `counter`... You need `var`.

Comment: Here are a few more suggestions: declare a doctype - add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the very top of your HTML (above the `<html>` element). Don't use `</html>` twice - that might've been a typo on your part. Enclose attribute values with quotes - `type="submit"` for example. Make sure you close elements properly - that means `<input>` should be `<input />`, and your `<table>` should have a `</table>`. Also, don't use `<center>` (and if you do, close it). Also I don't think `<input />` elements have a `type` of "box".

Comment: First you should fix the html [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to prevent any side effects on your Javascript (which has many other errors/problems (missing var, string != number, DOM Node != string, string as first parameter on `setTimeout`, ...))

Comment: Here's something that has a lot of the things I suggested fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/e6UEn/3/ - basically syntax/valid things. Hopefully you or someone can work from there to figure out the problem. Obviously, the images don't work, but can be easily replaced with an available URL (like from Google Images)

Comment: My suggestion, start from scratch. Take a good up to date [JavaScript tutorial](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/javascript-basics) and go step by step, making sure you understand the concepts and you're doing it the right way. JS is very particular, if you don't know that you're doing something wrong the code will become an unmaintainable mess (as you can see)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
alert(document.slots.slot1.src);
```

before your `switch()` and you'll see the real value you're checking. You're missing the extension (`.gif`) and the first part of the URL of the image (`http://.../`).

I think you should just remember the slots' values (in some variables) when you change their images, instead of reading them from the images' `src` attributes.

Comment: The value it gives me is the link to where the image is located. And I don`t understand where I should place the .gif extension

Comment: In your `case` statements. When you have `switch (x) { case "a": ... case "b": ...` it is testing if `x == "a"`, then if `x == "b"`, etc. which means that the value of the variable has to be exactly the same as the string in `case`. Your strings `document.slots.slot1` and `"number1test"` are not exactly equal when `"number1test"` is missing `http://.../` and the extension.

Comment: This worked, thank-you so much man, Been working on it all day, you can't imagine how Happy I am right now!

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing where you're setting document.slots.slot1.src = "number1test.gif" and the like, but nowhere where you're setting document.slots.slot = "number1test".

My guess is that you're switching on the wrong things, plus using the wrong values.

---

Ok, you want a more full answer.

Number one, your design here is erroneous.  You should never use something so fickle as an image source text to determine whether things are equivalent.  Do your equivalency tests when you do the randomization, or at least store your randomization results for later cross-checking.  Move your mod (%) out of the set of the source image, get your final numbers, check those numbers, and set both your "you won" and the images from the results of that.

Number two, you're doing your erroneous design wrong, because you're not using the variable you set in the first place (you're switching on the object), and then you're comparing against a value that you did not set it to (because you forgot the ".gif" and any junk that html may have added because it's a link).

Better?

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @user2396940: That's actually a good answer and you need to look into it to see if that resolves your problem. People is not here to rewrite your code.